# Excel macro VBA new workbook with one named sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to able to create a new workbook with only one sheet named "Options" and the following worksheets must start with "Sheet1" not with "Sheet2".
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you're looking for

This first creates a new workbook, then adds a new sheet at the beginning before renaming it to "Options". The rest of the sheets should then follow the default naming pattern

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub NewWorkbook()
    With Workbooks.Add
        With .Sheets.Add(Before:=.Sheets(1))
            .Name = "Options"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work exactly the way I wanted. I can try to explain better my problem. In the new workbook I would like to have only one sheet named "Options" and if a user wants to add additional sheets, it starts adding them from "Sheet1". Currently with your example I get a new workbook with the "Options" sheet and the "Sheet1" already opened. Also if I try to add a 3rd sheet, it starts from "Sheet3" and not "Sheet2" like I would like to.

Answer (score 3):

The code below will add a new `Workbook` with just 1 sheet named "Options".

However, regarding the second part, in order to start from "Sheet1" instead of "Sheet2" it involves adding code to the new created Workbook, since by default the new workbook already has 1 worksheet named "Options", so in fact you are adding a 2nd worksheet, so Excel automatically names it "Sheet2"

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateNewWB()

With Application
    .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    .Workbooks.Add
    .Sheets(1).Name = "Options"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Lesson for the day - .`SheetsInNewWorkbook`.  I never knew about that - I've always used `Workbooks.Add xlWBATWorksheet` to create a new workbook with a single sheet.  The help file even mentions `SheetsInNewWorkbook` when looking at `Workbooks.Add`.  But it does overwrite your current setting, so may be worth getting the code to remember the original setting before changing it - my workbooks are all being created with 5 sheets now.

Comment: I have to agree with Darren Bartrup-Cook. Play nice. Never change an Application setting without first recording the original state, then restoring it when you are through. Otherwise you can cause considerable aggravation for your users.